# "histogram" function: input strings and output dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, histogram

I'm trying to create a `histogram` function that takes strings and counts the number of times the strings was used and put into a dictionary. I'm still learning Python so any tips would be helpful.

```
>>> histogram('The Goose that Laid the Golden Egg') 
{'l': 2, 'n': 1, 'o': 3, 'h': 3, 'i': 1,'d': 2,   'e': 5, 'g': 4, ' ': 6, 'a': 2, 't': 4, 's': 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't solve this for you, but will give you a hint: use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Combine this with the fact that strings are iterable, and this gets you very close to a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Its what that [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is for :

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('The Goose that Laid the Golden Egg')
Counter({' ': 6, 'e': 4, 'h': 3, 'o': 3, 't': 3, 'a': 2, 'd': 2, 'G': 2, 'g': 2, 'i': 1, 'L': 1, 'l': 1, 's': 1, 'T': 1, 'E': 1, 'n': 1})
```

Comment: you're welcome , `This module implements specialized container datatypes providing alternatives to Python’s general purpose built-in containers, dict, list, set, and tuple.` its a necessary module in python's data structure ! attempt to learn it !